# How do I stop bookdown reordering punctuation?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown

I have forked `bookdown-minimal` [here](https://github.com/iangow/bookdown-minimal/) to produce the minimal reproducible example of my issue.

I want the following sentence to be rendered as is. That is, I want the full stop (period) to remain *outside* the quotes.

> This is the on-line version of "A Book".

I have made a minimal bookdown example here

The line `bibliography: [book.bib]` causes the sentence to be rendered using "Build book" as

> This is the on-line version of "A Book."

I know this is a convention of American English, but other languages (and other variants of English) don't do this and I don't want to do it in the real sentences I have (it seems that the issue occurs with other items of punctuation, such as `!` and `?`, that even American English puts in the correct place).

What is driving this behaviour? (Note that I am not actually including references in my minimal example.) Is there any easy way to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system respects the `lang` metadata variable. So if you are writing British English, then add this to your YAML metadata:

```yaml
lang: en-GB
```

The result should be

> This is the on-line version of “A Book”.

whereas

```yaml
lang: en-US
```

gives

> This is the on-line version of “A Book.”

---

If all else fails, you can resort to adding a [Lua filter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/lua-filters.html) which adds an invisible character like a [zero-width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner). This will prevent the reordering from happening as well.

```lua
function Quoted (quote)
  return {quote, pandoc.Str '\u{200d}'}
end
```

Note that you can take advantage of this trick on a per-case basis by using the `&zwj;` entity in your Markdown input:

```
This is the on-line version of "A Book"&zwj;.
```

Comment: The `lang: en-GB` thing does the trick. Do you know what in the knitr-pandoc machinery is using this parameter? What is being done with  `lang: en-US` is not quite correct even for American English.

The `&zwj;` thing would be a bit cumbersome (Markdown would start to resemble LaTeX).

Comment: The reordering is done by the citeproc processor, i.e. either pandoc or, for older versions, pandoc-citeproc. The Citation Style Language requires the feature and allows to [configure it](https://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#locale-options) in the style file, but the fact that it currently affects all punctuation is [considered a bug](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7005).

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting that it takes the `bibliography: [book.bib]` entry to trigger this behavio(u)r.

Comment: Note that `en-GB` appears to *leave things as they are*. So `This is the on-line version of "A Book."` comes out as just that. So `en-GB` provides the user with complete control (in this regard).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
This is the on-line version of "\text{A Book}"\text{.}
```

Comment: This is a good workaround when targeting LaTeX/PDF, but the `\text` commands will be missing in HTML and Docx generated from this.

Comment: Thanks, but this would be way too cumbersome for my use case. Solution above did the trick.